# How to resolve casing inconsistencies for GCP with Entra federation

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to add federation SSO for GCP using Entra. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/best-practices-for-federating#:%7E:text=The%20NameID%20value%20is%20expected%20to%20contain%20the%20primary%20email%20address%20of%20the%20user%20account%20to%20be%20authenticated.%20The%20email%20address%20is%20case%20sensitive.) says that the NameID passed back in the SAML assertion is case sensitive. How can I fix casing inconsistencies between the two IDPs. For example if on google I have a managed account with the email "myuser@somedomain.com" and on Entra the user has the UPN "Myuser.somedomain.com", how should I deal with this? Seems like you can change the UPN on Entra, but I'm not sure what unintended side effects that will have. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, changing the Entra UPN to match the case of the Google managed account email address have potential side effects like data migration issues or access disruptions for other systems relying on the original UPN. If possible, modify the Google managed account email address to match the case of the Entra UPN. This may not be feasible for existing accounts, but it can be a consideration for future setups.

You can also configure Entra to normalize the UPN to lowercase before sending it as the NameID in the SAML assertion to match the case of the Google managed account email address.

If you prioritize simplicity and can tolerate potential data migration or application disruptions, changing the Entra UPN might be the easiest solution. However, if minimizing side effects is crucial, normalizing NameIDs or modifying usernames might be preferable.

Comment: Can you point me to how to normalize the UPN before sending back? Is this a setting in Azure or something.